# split a list read in from file at the commas into a list of seperate elements

Tags: python, list, file, split

The problem with reading in the contents of a file, is that when read into a list, it formats it as one big string. Students need to be able to work with this "read" in data from the file, to isolate the ID number, and return the Student (for example).

I am aware of several methods that this could be done, for instance, regular expressions, converting to string, and using the split method, but would be interested, for teaching purposes, of the easiest, most elegant method (and by elegant, I mean avoiding multiple and unnecessary steps). Ideally, is there a way to read it into the list, directly from the text file, in the required format:

**For instance,**

instead of the current format (which also includes \n that I would need to strip):

```
['001,Joe,Bloggs,Test1:99,Test2:100,Test3:33\n', '002,Ash,Smith,Test1:22,Test2:63,Test3:99\n']
```

**Required format:** Either a **1d or 2d list** like below

```
[['001','Joe','Bloggs','Test1:99','Test2:100','Test3:33'],['002','Ash','Smith','Test1:22','Test2:63','Test3:99']]
```

I'd be happy for people to post solutions including reg ex and split string, as it will help others, but is there a way to do this more simply?

**Full Code listing with text file (repl it online:**

https://repl.it/J8jB/2

**Code:**

```
f = open("studentinfo.txt","r") 
myList = []
for line in f:
    myList.append(line)
print(myList)
print()
print()
print(myList[0])
myList.split(",")
print(myList)

#split the list where all the individual elements in the current string (in the list) are split up at the ","
```

**Text file:**

```
001,Joe,Bloggs,Test1:99,Test2:100,Test3:33
002,Ash,Smith,Test1:22,Test2:63,Test3:99
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once the list is built (or directly with the file handle as `l`, there's no need to store the list first) I would just `rstrip` and `split` in a list comprehension like this:

```
l = ['001,Joe,Bloggs,Test1:99,Test2:100,Test3:33\n', '002,Ash,Smith,Test1:22,Test2:63,Test3:99\n']

newl = [v.rstrip().split(",") for v in l]

print(newl)
```

result:

```
[['001', 'Joe', 'Bloggs', 'Test1:99', 'Test2:100', 'Test3:33'], ['002', 'Ash', 'Smith', 'Test1:22', 'Test2:63', 'Test3:99']]
```

for a flat list do a double loop instead (or use `itertools.chain.from_iterable`, well there are a lot of ways to do that):

```
newl = [x for v in l for x in v.rstrip().split(",")]
```

without listcomp (just for "readability" when you're not used to listcomps, after that, switch to listcomps :)):

```
newl = []
for v in l:
    newl.append(v.rstrip().split(","))
```

(use `extend` instead of `append` to get a flat list)

of course I always forget to mention `csv` which has default separator as comma and strips the newlines:

```
import csv
newl = list(csv.reader(l))
```

flat (using `itertools` this time):

```
newl = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(csv.reader(l)))
```

(`l` can be a file handle or a list of lines for the `csv` module)

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you. For the purposes of beginners who wouldn't want to then continue and loop through a 2d array, would you be able to additionally post a solution that creates a 1d list with all the elements in it sequentially?

Comment: Also, any comments on whether this is the most pythonic, easiest method would be appreciated. Is it preferred to read and manipulate directly from file, or read into list (build list) and then manipulate?

Comment: Finally, are you able to extend this (so the loop can be understood, if you get my meaning) and comment for those not familiar with list comprehensions. [v.rstrip().split(",") for v in myList]. Many Many thanks!

Comment: Your answer suggests that l can be a handle or a list of lines. Are you sure it can be a handle? I tried this and it didn't work....newerlist=list(csv.reader(f))
print(newerlist)     Error: TypeError: argument 1 must be an iterator

Comment: Yes I'm sure. check the type of `f`. `csv.reader` is more often used with open files than lists.

Comment: simpy this would not work though? newlist=list(csv.reader(myList))
print(newlist)    I would need read = csv.reader(f) ?? Just trying to get at shortest most elegant solution. Thank you

Comment: yes, that would work. `l` can be `f` or `myList` of your example.

Comment: I'm still waiting on anyone to add to their answer regarding producing a 1d list (with all elements) not two, 1d lists as the answer below provides. I have accepted this as the answer though, as it is the most elegant and does the job. Thank you and Serge Ballesta  too! :)

Comment: ok, since you accepted, my duty is to add the "flat" part, which is now done :)

Comment: you have to `import itertools`, like all modules.

Answer (score 2):

That is a good use case for the csv module:

```
import csv

with open("studentinfo.txt","r") as f:
    rd = csv.reader(f)
    lst = list(rd)    # lst is a list of lists in expected format
    ...               # further processing on lst
```

Alternatively, it is trivial to process the file line by line

```
with open("studentinfo.txt","r") as f:
    rd = csv.reader(f)
    for row in rd:          # row is list of fields
        ...                 # further processing on row
```

Comment: Perfect -this works. Elegant. Does the csv reader automatically deal with things like spaces. Could you comment on the elegance of this solution over the previous answer? Also, are you able to add to your answer to show the result in a 1d list as well as a 2d, as shown.

Comment: I had the same idea about csv so I edited my post. csv _is_ the natural way to handle this. I _never_ use `split` on a comma separated file at work, but curiously I always answer with `split` on SO...

Comment: with open("studentinfo.txt","r") as f:
    rd = csv.reader(f)
    for row in rd:
      newerlist=row
print(newerlist)   this still produces a 2d list???

Comment: @MissComputing: no I thought you want to know how to process individual sublists as 1D lists of fields

Comment: ah no, I meant to process the whole file as one single list (1d), so as to avoid learners (who have not gotten to nested looping yet) having to use a nested loop to iterate. I didn't want two 1d lists

Comment: @MissComputing: then you could append each row to a (initialy empty) list: `lst = []` `rd = csv.reader(f)` `for row in reader:` `lst.extend(row)`

Comment: Hm. I've tried that, but you see it still creates two 1d lists. Please have a look at this repl.it :) https://repl.it/JaqU/1

Comment: @MissComputing: the list must be initialized before entering the for loop, and only extended in it. Your current `repl` resets it on each line.